# Sets, Find an example of a strictly increasing sequence of sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Find an example of a strictly increasing sequence of sets
$_1 \subsetneq _2 \subsetneq _3 \subsetneq\dotsb$
for which union of all of these sets equals the set of all real numbers and intersection of all these sets equals the empty set.

#### My thoughts

Set $A = (i+1; i+2)$ is this sequence a solution?

#### Another problem:

Find an example of a strictly decreasing sequence of sets
$_1 \supsetneq _2 \supsetneq _3 \supsetneq  \dotsb$
for which
$$ \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} B_i = \mathbb{R}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} B_i = \varnothing. $$

#### My thoughts

Set $C = (1/(i+1); 1/(i+2) )$.

Comment: For A, they are not contained within each other right?

Comment: They can contain each other as long as their union = to real numbers and intersection= empty set, and they also subsets

Answer (score 1):

Neither example works in your case.

- Your first example only covers positive reals, not negatives.
- Your second example will never cover numbers outside of the interval $[-1,1]$, and thus their union can not be $\Bbb R$.

---

I would just define the sets like this... For your first example,

$$A_n = (-n+1,n-1)$$

Thus, $A_1 = (0,0) = \emptyset$, $A_2 = (-1,1)$, $A_3 = (-2,2)$, and so on.

---

For your second case, let $B_1 = \Bbb R$, and then let $B_n = (n, \infty)$ for $n \ge 2$.

Thus, $B_1 = (-\infty,\infty)$, $B_2 = (2,\infty)$, $B_3 = (3,\infty)$, $B_4 = (4,\infty)$, and so on.

---

I'll leave the properties for you to verify.

Comment: but are they proper subsets? (set A) (-1;1) is not in (-2;2) set

Comment: Yes it is? Every number between $-1$ and $1$ is also a number between $-2$ and $2$.